# Как в google chrome программно выбрать микрофон?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то программно выбрать мирофон в хроме? При условии того что есть полный доступ к машине на которой запускается браузер.

Может это можно как-то сделать на JavaScipt? Если это можно реализовать на JS, то потом можно сделать расширение, через `tampermonkey` или запустить скрипт через `webdriver Selenium`.

Нашел следующий пример, который выводит в консоль список аудиоустройств. Можно ли также через консоль сменить микрофон? Пожалуйста дайте пример, если это возможно. Если это не возможно, то пожалуйста напишите почему не получится и как можно по другому попытаться решить задачу.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
            " id = " + device.deviceId);
  });
})
```

Comment: Может это? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, что-то не могу понять, как это юзать. Можно пример?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно выбрать девайс с помощью метода [setSinkId(deviceId)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId) как указано в  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices

```
element.setSinkId(sinkId)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Audio output device attached: ' + sinkId);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: К сож. не работает в большинстве случаев. В т.ч. Chrome 66.0.3359.139 Linux

Answer (score 1):

Нет, но можно сделать кастомный конфиг для хрома, где разрешен микрофон и в `exceptions` добавлено:

```
"media_stream_mic":{"http://localhost:1337,*":
                                          {"last_used":1470931206,
                                           "setting":1} },
```

и селениуму передавать эти настройки.

Comment: Я знаю этот способ. Есть параметр `default_audio_capture_device` в файле `"ChromeUserDataDir + "\\Default\\Preferences"`. Этот параметр сохраняет последний выбранный микрофон и при перезапуске хром его достает.

Comment: Хотелось-бы без перезапуска сделать.. Мб через память как-то залезть в хром. Тот-же cheat engine..